# is there any way to extract maximum value from the result set which came after combining two queries with same column through union

Tags: sql

I used a select query and in from I have put both the queries by using union and it gives the desired result but the moment I add extra column("cast('Made' as nvarchar) as Status" in first query and "cast('Received' as nvarchar) as Status" in second query) in both the sub query I am not getting the max value instead getting the all rows of both the query.

Comment: Provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: If I provide query will it be helpful